# Postgre and docker error: Error response from daemon: invalid mode

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use this block of code in gitbash:

```
winpty docker run -it -e postgres_users="root" -e postgres_password="root" -e postgres_db="ny_taxi" -v c:/Users/majak/desktop/course/myfiles/week_1:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres:13
```

And I get an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: \Program Files\Git\var\lib\pos
tgresql\data.
```

This is my yaml file:

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
```

why do I get this error and how do I fix it?